# Not able to insert Data into the database in MFC application with MS access db

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++, mfc

The code I have written for inserting data in the DB is: Now, after entering details from the frontend, I am clicking on the Register button, but No action is happening ??  the table for this is having the following columns:

- `lastName`
- `firstName`
- `DateOfBirth`
- `Sex`
- `Status`
- `MRN`
- `Encounter_Type`
- `Person_ID`

All of these are short text types.

Database instance is correct as it is working for other modules.

```cpp
void CPatientRegistrationDlg::OnBnClickedRegister()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CSingLeton* st;
    st = CSingLeton::getInstance();

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    CTime tDate = CTime::GetCurrentTime();
    m_DateOfBirthCtrl.GetTime(tDate);
    CString sDate = tDate.Format("%Y-%m-%d");
    time_t Time = time(0);
    struct tm* ti = localtime(&Time);
    int nCuuretnDay = ti->tm_mday;
    int nCurrentMonth = 1 + ti->tm_mon;
    int nCurrentYear = 1900 + ti->tm_year;

    if (m_FirstNameCtrl.GetWindowTextLength() == 0 || m_LastNameCtrl.GetWindowTextLength() == 0 || m_GenderCtrl.GetCurSel() < 0 || m_EncounterCtrl.GetCurSel() < 0 || m_StatusCtrl.GetCurSel() < 0)
    {
        m_sMessage.LoadString(IDS_WARNINGMESSAGE);
        m_sCaption.LoadString(IDS_WARNINGCAPTION);
        ::MessageBox(this->GetSafeHwnd(), m_sMessage, m_sCaption, MB_ICONWARNING);
    }
    else
    {
        if (OnValidatePatientFirstName() && OnValidatePatientLastName())
        {
            CString sGender;
            m_GenderCtrl.GetWindowText(sGender);
            CString sEncounterType;
            m_EncounterCtrl.GetWindowText(sEncounterType);
            CString  sStatus;
            m_StatusCtrl.GetWindowText(sStatus);
            CString sLastName;
            m_LastNameCtrl.GetWindowText(sLastName);
            CString sFirstName;
            m_FirstNameCtrl.GetWindowText(sFirstName);
            CString sMrn = OnGetPatientMrn();
            if (!sMrn.IsEmpty())
            {
                try
                {
                    std::string sSqlString = "INSERT INTO Person_table VALUES ('" + ConvertCStringToString(sLastName) + "', '" + ConvertCStringToString(sFirstName) + "', '" + ConvertCStringToString(sDate) + "','" + ConvertCStringToString(sGender) + "', '" + ConvertCStringToString(sStatus) + "','" + ConvertCStringToString(sMrn) + "','" + ConvertCStringToString(sEncounterType) + "')";
                    st->ExecuteSQL(ConvertStringToCString(sSqlString));
                    m_sMessage.LoadString(IDS_PATIENTMRN);
                    m_sCaption.LoadString(IDS_MRNNOTE);
                    ::MessageBox(this->GetSafeHwnd(), m_sMessage + _T(" ") + sMrn, m_sCaption, MB_OK);
                    m_FirstNameCtrl.SetWindowText(_T(""));
                    m_LastNameCtrl.SetWindowText(_T(""));
                    m_StatusCtrl.SetCurSel(-1);
                    m_EncounterCtrl.SetCurSel(-1);
                    m_GenderCtrl.SetCurSel(-1);
                    ResetDate(nCurrentYear, nCurrentMonth, nCuuretnDay);
                }
                catch (CDBException* e)
                {
                    OutputDebugString(e->m_strError);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Single Step  (F10) through this function, and tell us what happens.

Comment: I am not familiar with this approach. I use `CDatabase:->ExecuteSQL(....)`.